Andriod emulator is not opening and it is showing device emulator-5554 is offline
see this image emulator is not opening and from 1 hour it is showing connected to emulator but emulator is not opening below of this image when i run the command flutter doctor it is showing Device emulator-5554 is offline.

i search on google some people are saying adb kill-server command can resolve this problem but its not working

Welcome to SO. Please provide relevant code to show your attempts to solve the issue. This will make it much easier to reproduce the issue and see what's going on.


To resolve this issue, simply select "Wipe data".
enter image description here


If that doesn't work, go to the emulated device, enable developer options, and then enable USB debugging.

